# SDK Version Specifications in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, manifest

I am an experienced Android developer using Eclipse, but one thing still mystifies me. Namely SDK version specifications. In particular, I find several places where SDK versions are specified:

1. Project Properties: Android:  Project Build Target
2. Manifest: minSdkVersion
3. Manifest: targetSdkVersion
4. Manifest: maxSdkVersion

Below are my guesses about usage (probably wrong):

**Project Properties: Project Build Type**
Ok, seems fairly straightforward. I believe this specifies the API "library" to use.

**Manifest: minSdkVersion**
My guess is that this is the minimum level (as specified above) for checking methods used. Ok, but seems redundant. Wouldn't the compiler just bark at me if I used an unsupported method?

**Manifest: targetSdkVersion**
Can't figure this one out. If I call only supported methods, what additionally does this setting do?

**Manifest: maxSdkVersion**
Even more mysterious. Why would you ever want to limit the max version?  Aren't they backward compatible?

The official doc is rather sparse on the functionality of these settings. Can anybody give me some insight?

Comment: See this article: https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android: Project Build Target**

When you select a project build target version it means you are apk or classes will be compiled according to selected SDK. for ex - if you select project build target 16 and try to use annotation @JavaScriptInterface it will not find because this annotation is available in above that target.

**Manifest: minSdkVersion**

If you define minimum SDK version, an Android users who are using below the specified minimum SDK version can't use your app.

For more info from google Docs:

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the
>   application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from
>   installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the
>   value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this
>   attribute.

**Manifest: targetSdkVersion**

The `targetSdkVersion` has nothing to do with how your app is compiled or what APIs you can utilize. The `targetSdkVersion` is supposed to indicate that you have tested your app on (presumably up to and including) the version you specify. This is more like a certification or sign off you are giving the Android OS as a hint to how it should handle your app in terms of OS features.

For example, as the documentation states:

> For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to
>   apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android
>   3.0 or higher...

The Android OS, at runtime, may change how your app is stylized or otherwise executed in the context of the OS based on this value. There are a few other known examples that are influenced by this value and that list is likely to only increase over time.

For all practical purposes, most apps are going to want to set `targetSdkVersion` to the latest released version of the API. This will ensure your app looks as good as possible on the most recent Android devices. If you do not specify the `targetSdkVersion`, it defaults to the `minSdkVersion`.

**Manifest: maxSdkVersion**

If you define `maxSdkVersion` users who are using an android phone running SDK version more than what you defined in `maxSdkVersion` can't use your app.

For more info from google Docs:

> An application declaring maxSdkVersion="5" in its manifest is
>   published on Google Play. A user whose device is running Android 1.6
>   (API Level 4) downloads and installs the app. After a few weeks, the
>   user receives an over-the-air system update to Android 2.0 (API Level
>   5). After the update is installed, the system checks the application's
>   `maxSdkVersion` and successfully re-validates it. The application
>   functions as normal. However, sometime later, the device receives
>   another system update, this time to Android 2.0.1 (API Level 6). After
>   the update, the system can no longer re-validate the application
>   because the system's own API Level (6) is now higher than the maximum
>   supported by the application (5). The system prevents the application
>   from being visible to the user, in effect removing it from the device.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Other answers were also great but I can only accept one.

Answer (score 0):

**Project Properties: Project Build Type** - Yes this will pick up the android.jar and also the build tools version.

**Manifest: minSdkVersion** - This is not just for the compilation purpose but also used by google play to filter the application. 
Secondly, if you have any functionality which is not available below a certain version but required by your application.

**Manifest: targetSdkVersion** - As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect. You can disable such compatibility behaviors by specifying targetSdkVersion to match the API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).

**Manifest: maxSdkVersion** - not recommended. This will restrict your app onto any version higher that the specified maxSdkVersion.

In Android 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, and 2.0.1, the system checks the value of this attribute when installing an application and when re-validating the application after a system update.
However, future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer check or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or re-validation

There is no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible. Your application should work properly on new versions, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development best practices. Second, note that in some cases, declaring the attribute can result in your application being removed from users' devices after a system update to a higher API Level. Most devices on which your application is likely to be installed will receive periodic system updates over the air, so you should consider their effect on your application before setting this attribute.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html covers it all